# Extracting coordinates from a Mathematica spline graphics

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can one extract the coordinates of all the points which make up the following graphics (here just an example)?

```
 spl = BSplineCurve[{{-.4, -.3}, {0, -.6}, {.4, -.3}, {0, -1.2}}, 
      SplineClosed -> True] ;
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, spl}]
```

The problem is that if I add `//FullForm` to the last line there is no point coordinates in the output, so no pattern to use to make that extraction:
With a `Plot`or `CoutourPlot` output I would have coded  `Flatten[Cases[Normal@output, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity], 1]`
which is not possible here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The b-spline is itself a graphics primitive so you cant pull out the "line" like that.

You need to use the related `BSplineFunction` to generate your points:

```
 pts=BSplineFunction[{{-.4, -.3}, {0, -.6}, {.4, -.3}, {0, -1.2}}, 
        SplineClosed -> True] /@ Range[0, 1, .01];


 Graphics@Line@pts
```

[image]

If you need to extract from a graphic you can do this:

```
Cases[graphics, BSplineCurve[a__] :> BSplineFunction[a], Infinity]
```

but you still need to feed it a table of parameter values to get your points.

Comment: Thanks! You opened a door for me for plenty of new possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

To extract just the control points you can go:

```
curveData=Cases[graphics, BSplineCurve[a__] :>  a, Infinity]
```

how many BSplineCurves were found in the graphic?

```
Length[curveData]
```

here are the control points of one of them

```
curveData// First // MatrixForm
```

If you have a list of BSplineFunctions you can find out much more

so first convert the BSplineCurves to BSplineFunctions as the previous post

```
bfs =Cases[graphics, BSplineCurve[a__] :> BSplineFunction[a], Infinity]
```

then you could just go

```
Inputform[bfs]
```

and parse the result, but it is cleaner to go:

```
cdata = Cases[bfs, BSplineFunction[a__] :> a, Infinity]; 
d = Partition[cdata, 9];
```

This is Mathematica 11. other versions may need different partitioning

each element of d will be something like:

```
d[[1]] // MatrixForm

1
{{0.,1.}}
{3}
{False}
{{{0.,0.,0.},{0.,298.986,167.077},{0.,497.083,497.459},{0.,503.603,839.898}},Automatic}
{{0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.}}
{0}
MachinePrecision
Unevaluated
```

The 5th element contains the control point coordinates. The sixth corresponds to the knots. The other elements look familiar but let us not post our guesses!